# FFmpeg filter complex with bitdepth and sample rate

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got this code to split audio files and I can't figure out how to set the bitdepth to s32 and sample rate to 48000. Here is the code

```sh
ffmpeg -i "audioFile.wav" -filter_complex channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[FL][FR] -write_bext 1 -map [FL] "audioFile.L.wav" -write_bext 1 -map [FR] "audioFile.R.wav"
```

I can set it on its own without splitting with the command below, but can't figure how to combine the below code with the above one since you can't use `-af` and `-filter_complex` in the same command.

`-af aformat=sample_fmts=s32:sample_rates=48000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This combination of `-filter_complex` should work for you:

```
-filter_complex "[0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=s32:sample_rates=48000[a];[a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[FL][FR]"
```

Comment: Tyvm @Lex. Ffmpeg has always been confusing for me. Just in case anyone runs into problems I also had to specify the codec to achieve a 1:1 24bit change when converting otherwise it would still force it to 16 bit. Here is the final code for my filter_complex
```ffmpeg -i "audioFile.wav" -filter_complex [0:a]aformat=sample_fmts=s32:sample_rates=48000[a];[a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[FL][FR] -acodec pcm_s24le -write_bext 1 -map [FL] "audioFile.L.wav" -acodec pcm_s24le -write_bext 1 -map [FR] "audioFile.R.wav"```